# Supress long html output with kable_styling

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra, pkgdown

One of the functions in my package produces a table using `kable()` and `kable_styling()`. When I run this code, I see both the output in the viewer and the long HTML code in the console. I see solutions for excluding the HTML output in an Rmd but not for a function. It also only displays the code when I use `pkgdown::build_site()`

I have tried `invisible()`, `sink()` and I'm using the latest version of `kableExtra` (1.1.0)

How can I get it to only show the result in the viewer and also show up correctly in the function's reference page?

I'm not sure how to reprex the `pkgdown` stuff but this should be enough to make some headway.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

mpg %>% 
  kable(format = "html") %>% 
  kable_styling()

# same result
x <- mpg %>% kable(format = "html")

kable_styling(x)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `capture.output` to stop printing the output in console but still displaying it in viewer.

```
x <- mpg %>% kable(format = "html") %>% kable_styling() %>% capture.output()
```

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have found that on my own. Curious that it only works when there is an assignment. I was trying to call it without.